# Resend a mailing to recipients who did not open

Tags: civimail

Our communications staff wants to be able to resend a mailing (or send a new mailing) to recipients who did not open a previous mailing. Of course, this is possible by creating a group from the "unique opens" of the first mailing, and then excluding that group in the new mailing.

Unfortunately, there are a number of steps with this, and it seems like a sufficiently useful workflow that I'd be interested in it as a new core feature. Other mass mailing services like Constant Contact have a "resend to non-openers" feature.

Before I open an feature request issue in lab.civicrm.org, I wanted to test it here to see if others feel it might be a worthwhile feature, or if there is some other way to streamline the workflow.

Comment: Sounds like a useful contribution to civicrm to me. Note, it is unlikely to progress without funding. You may want to also approach some Partners for a quote to get an idea of the scope of work to have it as an Extension.

Comment: This is a good idea - I've actually been asked to write something similar in the past, but funding didn't come through.

Comment: How about (may be easier and provide more options) -> getting the unique opens in a report template. Then you can select / filter /  create a group / export.

Comment: I agree such functionality would be useful. As a slightly related thing, I just made this: https://github.com/artfulrobot/resendmailing which helps with the job of resending a mailing to search results.

Comment: Personally I do think this a bad idea. If I receive an e-mail again because I did not open it in the first time why would I open it the second time? (And a side note regarding GDPR, if one the receivers is European Citizen you have to think carefully about tracking who opened the mail and who not.)

Comment: Just another note on this. The mechanism by which opens are tracked will require the user to "view" images. While some clients display images by default (gmail does) others do not. So the stats in civicrm will not exactly match who has seen the email in the real world. In saying this resenting the email is not necessary bad but perhaps take this into account - and perhaps trigger off a different metric - like people who didn't click on the cta - which is exact.

Comment: I disagree with @JaapJansma-CiviCooP that it is, on the face of it, a bad idea. There are many reasons a person may not have opened an email: it may have been filtered into another "inbox" (<sarcasm> thanks, Google</sarcasm>), it may have arrived during vacation week and gotten lost in a deluge, it may have been mistakenly deleted, it may have been deferred by the user and forgotten about,  who knows.

Comment: Since certain large email providers now filter out tracking pixels, the open rate is now really unreliable (clicks, however, are still fine), so the benefit of this feature is now a lot less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a few steps, using my [Resend Mailing extension](https://github.com/artfulrobot/resendmailing)

1. Do a search for people who were sent the mailing but have not opened it.

   1. **Search » Advanced Search**
   2. Open the **Mailings** bit
   3. Enter the name of the mailing.
   4. Select "Trackable Opens" - "Unopened / hidden"
2. Click the 'all' option on the search results, then choose 'Email - resend a CiviMail mailing'
3. Tweak that mailing as you wish and hit send. Note that you'll need to select a suitable "unsubscribe group". If your original mailing was sent to a group called X then choosing X would be a sensible choice there.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @PhilMoriceBrubaker yes I believe it works fine for the stated use case but take care with the 'experimental' resend to single contact feature, re https://github.com/artfulrobot/resendmailing/issues/3