# Resend email to non-openers

Tags: civimail, contacts, email

We would like to be able to resend a mailing (or send an edited version of the original mailing) to recipients who did not open the original mailing.

While there are workarounds — such as creating a new group — they take extra steps and can be especially confusing when trying to add a useful unsubscribe link.

A similar question was previously [posted here in February 2019](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/28601/9702). I am wondering if any progress has been made on this feature?

Thank you!

Comment: How about make a group of those who did open, then set that Group to Exclude for your next mailing?

Comment: Definitely a good work around — thanks! I'd still hope a quicker feature could be made in the future...

Comment: I've received this request before, but once I point out that [email open rates are inaccurate bordering on useless](https://developermedia.com/email-open-rates-misleading-metrics-best-practices-2/) their desire to fund an extension to do this evaporates.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM, Your request can be done via smart group as a work around to avoid 10 step process you can implement an extension that would calculate the recipients based on 'Re-use' mailing link or a drop down of previous mailing lists

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this as an "answer" due to Stackexchanges weird view that I can answer with less than 50 reputation, but not comment. I find that odd - sorry for the commentary.

Anyway, one answer I saw recommended "not doing this" as people may be put off by multiple emails.

I would suggest that any action taken have steps to make it measurable. Maybe this is a great idea, maybe it is simply an ok action and maybe it is bad.

I would watch open rates (bearing in mind that Google will distort that through pixel placement) as well as response rates and unsub rates.

I personally think this is a great idea but you might be able to get even more traction out of it (in terms of code sharing versus hiring) by making it more broadly applicable.

This can be done by a series of steps to smart groups, perhaps a way to automate smart group work flows would be better than a specific task?

Good luck!